# meaning of processor bandwidth

Tags: real-time

My question is about something make me confused. I have read some references about real-time scheduling policies, and I have read about Constant Bandwidth Server policy which gives a constant bandwidth for each task from the processor to be execute.

My question is what is the meaning of processor bandwidth?

Comment: Please cite what you read.

Comment: Would it make sense if you think of a synonym "processor time" or "processor time slot" for "processor bandwidth"?